# Pass data to nested component in react.js

Tags: reactjs

I have Three components like below

`A.js`

```
import React, { Component } from 'react';
import B from './B';
export class A extends Component {
    ajaxmethod = () => {
        //fetching data through ajax method.

    }
    render() {
        return (
            <div>
                <B/>
            </div>
        );
    }
}
```

`B.js`

```
import React, { Component } from 'react';
import C from './C';

//this is a Modal container
export class B extends Component {
    render() {
        return (
            <div>
                <C/>
            </div>
        );
    }
}
```

`C.js`

```
import React, { Component } from 'react';

//this is Modal elements
export class C extends Component {
    render() {
        return (
            <div>
                I need to display data here from A Component
            </div>
        );
    }
}
```

There is button in `A.js` component. Which button displays a modal (`B.js`) when clicked. `B.js` is modal container component. `C.js` is modal element component. I have a AJAX method in `A.js` component. I would like to display data in `C.js` from `A.js`.

How can I do that ?

**UPDATE**

I used below code in `B.js` component.

```
static getDerivedStateFromProps(nextProps) {
    return {
      modalchildOpen: nextProps.modelStatus
    };
  }
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Well, A can just set its own state after the ajax call finishes, then pass it as a props to B, then B will pass it down to C.

Something like:

A.js

```
import React, { Component } from 'react';
import B from './B';
export class A extends Component {
    ajaxmethod = () => {
        // set loading state to true
        this.setState({ loading: true });
        ajax()
          .then(data => {
             // ajax request finished, set data to state and set loading to false
             this.setState({ fetchedData: data, loading: false });
          })
    }

    renderModal() {
        const { fetchedData, loading } = this.state;

        // check if data fetch successful and is currently not loading other data, then render
        if (fetchedData.status === 'OK' && !loading) { 
          return <B fetchedData={fetchedData} />;
        }
    }

    render() {
        return (
            <div>
                {this.renderModal()}
            </div>
        );
    }
}
```

B.js

```
import React, { Component } from 'react';
import C from './C';

//this is a Modal container
export class B extends Component {
    render() {
        return (
            <div>
                <C fetchedData={this.props.fetchedData} />
            </div>
        );
    }
}
```

And then in C.js, you can just access `this.props.fetchedData`.

Comment: Thanks @Jackyef. I did like you. But I found that modal is displayed before the data displayed and modal is displaying previous clicked data. What can I do now ?

Comment: In A, you can first check if this.props.fetchedData exist to decide whether to render B or not. You can also add a loading state and set it to true when ajax is in process. Then, only render when loading is false. Check my updated answer.

Answer (score 1):

The success callback for the Ajax request should set a state property in `A`:

```
this.setState({data: getYourDataFromTheResponse});
```

Pass this as one of the props of `B`:

```
<B data={this.state.data} />
```

And `B` should pass it on to one of the props of `C`:

```
<C data={this.props.data} />
```

Comment: Thanks @Aasmund Eldhuset. I did like you. But I found that modal is displayed before the data displayed and modal is displaying previous clicked data. What can I do now ?

Comment: You can show the modal only if the data is set: `{this.props.data && <B data={this.props.data} />}`. `A` will also need to define a callback function that will do `this.setState({data: null});` and send that as another prop to `B`, which must call that callback when the modal closes. That way, you won't see old data the next time the modal opens.

Answer (score 1):

There are three options:-

```
1. Use redux store(global store);
2. Use Context API if the version is React v16.3
3. Props Bouncing
```

1. Use redux store(global store)

It is bit complex. You should know about redux store, actions, reducers then save your data in store and fetch in any component using mapStateToProps.

https://redux.js.org/basics/store

2. context Api:-

If you are using latest version of react then it will provide you context api feature.

```
const AppContext = React.createContext()

export class A extends Component {
    ajaxmethod = () => {
        //fetching data through ajax method.
        this.setState({data: response})
    }
    render() {
        return (
            <AppContext.Provider value={this.state}>
                <B/>
            </AppContext.Provider>
        );
    }
}

B.js component similar to your created component

C.js

    export class C extends Component {
        render() {


     return (
            <AppContext.Consumer>
            {(data) => {
               // here your data
            }}
          </AppContext.Consumer>
        );
    }
}
```

https://hackernoon.com/how-to-use-the-new-react-context-api-fce011e7d87

3. Props Bouncing:-

A.js

```
import React, { Component } from 'react';
import B from './B';

    export class A extends Component {
        ajaxmethod = () => {
            //fetching data through ajax method.
            this.setState({data: response});

        }
        render() {
            return (
                <div>
                    <B data={this.state.data}/>
                </div>
            );
        }
    }
```

B.js

```
import React, { Component } from 'react';
import C from './C';

    //this is a Modal container
    export class B extends Component {
        render() {
            return (
                <div>
                    <C {...this.props}/>
                </div>
            );
        }
    }

C.js

import React, { Component } from 'react';

//this is Modal elements
export class C extends Component {
    render() {
        return (
            <div>
                {this.props.data} // you can use your data here.
            </div>
        );
    }
}
```